# How to handle browser level notification using Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am automating some test cases using Selenium Webdriver and core Java. In Chrome browser for one test case on clicking button I am getting a browser level notification 'Show notifications with options Allow and Block'.
I want to select Allow option. Does anyone know how to handle this kind of notifications using Selenium webdriver?

Please refer to the following snapshot for more details
[image]

Answer (score 5):

Please Follow below steps :

**A) USING JAVA :**

> **For Old Chrome Version (<50):**

```
//Create a instance of ChromeOptions class
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

//Add chrome switch to disable notification - "**--disable-notifications**"
options.addArguments("--disable-notifications");

//Set path for driver exe 
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","path/to/driver/exe");

//Pass ChromeOptions instance to ChromeDriver Constructor
WebDriver driver =new ChromeDriver(options);
```

---

> **For New Chrome Version (>50):**

```
//Create a map to store  preferences 
Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();

//add key and value to map as follow to switch off browser notification
//Pass the argument 1 to allow and 2 to block
prefs.put("profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications", 2);

//Create an instance of ChromeOptions 
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

// set ExperimentalOption - prefs 
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);

//Now Pass ChromeOptions instance to ChromeDriver Constructor to initialize chrome driver which will switch off this browser notification on the chrome browser
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

---

> **For Firefox :**

```
    WebDriver driver ;
    FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
    profile.setPreference("permissions.default.desktop-notification", 1);
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
    capabilities.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, profile);
    driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
    driver.get("http://google.com");
```

---

**B) USING PYTHON :**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

option = Options()

option.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
option.add_argument("start-maximized")
option.add_argument("--disable-extensions")

# Pass the argument 1 to allow and 2 to block
option.add_experimental_option("prefs", { 
    "profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 1 
})

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=option, executable_path='path-of- 
driver\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.facebook.com')
```

**C) USING C#:**

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArguments("--disable-notifications"); // to disable notification
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Comment: user2085714 asked how to enable notifications, not disable them.

Comment: May I know how to get same from JavaScript ?

Answer (score 3):

```
WebDriver driver ;
        FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
        profile.setPreference("permissions.default.desktop-notification", 1);
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
        capabilities.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, profile);
        driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
        driver.get("your Web site");
```

Answer (score 2):

Steps to handle this type of requirements:

1. Open Firefox Profile manager (Go to Start Menu, Type `firefox.exe -p` to launch profile manager)
2. Create a new Profile (Ex. name of Profile is `customfirefox`)
3. Navigate to `about:permissions`
4. Do the required configurations and Save the Profile

Now use the newly created Profile to run your test by invoking the Firefox

```
ProfilesIni ffProfiles = new ProfilesIni();
FirefoxProfile profile = ffProfiles.getProfile("customfirefox");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

This will always use the firefox with the custom configurations saved on the profile.

Hope this works for you..!!!

Good luck.

Comment: Hi, sorry to forget browser. i am using chrome browser. any solution for chrome browser

Answer (score 2):

You can use below code to allow chrome to send notifications:

```
ChromeOptions options=new ChromeOptions();
Map<String, Object> prefs=new HashMap<String,Object>();
prefs.put("profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications", 1);
//1-Allow, 2-Block, 0-default
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs",prefs);
ChromeDriver driver=new ChromeDriver(options);
```

It works perfectly for me. Let me know if it doesn't work for you. 
Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding,this pop-ups not javascripts one.So selenium won't handle them. Same kinda,authentication popup also there , which we automate via a hack like http://username:password@www.test.com , here giving user name and password in url itself. 
In your case the way Praveen mentioned you have to create browser profile (FF or chrome ).In chrome, profile can be create  via desired cabilities options or chrome options function.

Answer (score -1):

update: 
Please use incognito mode to avoid such browser-level notifications and cookies issue.

Comment: I tried this and this did not work for me.
This pop-up appears not to be an alert...

Comment: Try increasing the Wait time and check.

Comment: Else we have to use ROBO class for accepting/ dismissing the prompt

Comment: No, this pop-up is simply not an alert.
To disable it I just added 
options.addArguments("disable-notifications");
and it worked while your answer did not

Comment: @Eliyahu My answer was for accepting notifications not disabling !

Comment: This will NOT work anyway since this is NOT an alert.