# I want to click on "Allow" button in notification popup, instead of blocking pop-up using selenium

Tags: selenium, popup

Below is the snap how the popup looking like :

[image]

While launch [this URL](https://www.makemytrip.com/), it shows a notification pop-up asking for allow or block. I want to click on the buttons "Allow" and "Block" instead of disabling pop-up.

Please help me how do I do this using Selenium Webdriver using java

Comment: Have you tried using AutoIt to click on that

Comment: no I didn't tried using AutoIt

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle browser level notification using Selenium Webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38367762/how-to-handle-browser-level-notification-using-selenium-webdriver)

Answer (score 0):

```
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("--disable-notifications");
```