# How to validate browser notifications using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, push-notification, webdriver

I am Automating one test case using Selenium Webdriver and core Java,in which on clicking one button I get browser level notification 'Show notifications with options Allow and Block'. After clicking "Allow" button, I want to validate contents of web push notifications that come as well as click on them. Does anybody know how to do that through selenium.Notifications will come something like this [facebook chrome notifications](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjovp.png)

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNPYP.png]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: @DebanjanB: Thanks DebanjanB, i have edited my question.

Comment: If that is the alert , you can use this code :  Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
alert.getText();

Comment: Did You try to locate this as simple page element? try to locate it as frame, alert, or simple panel with web elements and interact with them, find text, or "x" or whatever and do interaction.

Comment: what do you mean by the simple panel, I have tried alert and frames. For Alert, it is simply showing exception that alert is not open. I guess it does not consider notification optin popup as alert, the same thing goes with frames as well, I tried frames on different indexes, by names as well, nothing worked

Comment: Hi, have you able to solve this? I also want to automate this kind of push notification.

Comment: If I got it right, you would like to automate web-notifications. There are many links how to deactive webnotification, but I did'nt found a solution to automated it. Here is a link to show a notification on your browser:
[link](https://whatwebcando.today/local-notifications.html)

Answer (score 1):

For my test in Chrome I used the following to check if push notification is visible.

```
//SITE: 
 driver.get("http://makemytrip.com/");

//Test for PUSH NOTIFICATION

if(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[id='webpush-bubble']" )).isDisplayed()) {
   System.out.println("Push Prompt is Present");

//Popup active(as iFrame) so navigate in it and get text
//See=> https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/31693/how-to-read-html-source-from-iframe-using-selinium-webdriver
  WebElement iFrame = driver.findElements(By.tagName("iframe")).get(6); 
 driver.switchTo().frame(iFrame);
          System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='description']")).getText());
//Then switch back to normal content for any other navigation           
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();

    } else {
        System.out.println("Push Prompt NOT Present");
    }
```

Comment: This checks something in the DOM model, but the OP asked how to handle a browser-native notification (created with the `Notification` Javascript API).

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there is no way to handle it natively via Webdriver.

However, if you have control over the source code of the web-site (or can ask the devs to add a few lines), there actually is a way to test it.

Just save the created notification in a global Javascript variable:

```
var lastNotification;

// Later in the code where the notification is created...
let notification = new Notification(...);
// ... save it to be accessed from WebDriver tests. Also could be pushed to a list if many notifications can be present at the same time.
lastNotification = notification;
```

Then from your WebDriver you can wait for the notification to appear (if needed):

```
new WebDriverWait(...).until(ExpectedConditions.jsReturnsValue("return lastNotification");
```

Then you can click on it (or do anything the `Notification` Javascript API allows you to do):

```
JavascriptExecutor jsDriver = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
jsDriver.executeScript("lastNotification.dispatchEvent(new Event('click'))");
```

Answer (score -1):

You can control Firefox profile-wide preference to allow web-notification.

```
profile.setPreference("permissions.default.desktop-notification", 1);
```

See almost duplicated question and answer for more informations : https://stackoverflow.com/a/49111281/1079254

Comment: This only allows the notifications to show up, but doesn't help to actually handle them (detect them, click on them or close them, etc). If you need this, check out my answer :)